# Traer todas las facturas y detalles en laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

muchachos una consulta quiero obtener una lista de facturas con sus detalles agrupadas por cliente en Laravel,tengo 2 tablas *Facturas*, *Detalles_Factura*,

La consulta que tengo es;

```
$Factura = Detalles_Factura::join('Factura','Factura.id','=','Detalles_Factura.idFactura')->Select('Factura.Cliente',Detalles_Factura::raw('Detalles as Descripcion'))->groupBy('Factura.Cliente')->get();
```

Esto me trae los detalles con los nombre del cliente por fila, no sé si es posible traer un array de array

```
Producto 1 , Cliente:Jose
Producto 2 ,Cliente:Jose
Producto 3, Cliente:Jose
Producto 1, Cliente:Juan
Producto 2, Cliente:Juan
Producto 1, Cliente:Rosa
Producto 2, Cliente:Rosa
Producto 3, Cliente:Rosa
Producto 4, Cliente:Rosa
```

El requerimiento es obtener las facturas de esto modo:

```
Cliente: José
Producto 1
Producto 2
Producto 3
Cliente: Juan
Producto 1
Producto 2
Cliente: Rosa
Producto 1
Producto 2
Producto 3
Producto 4
```

Comment: esa respuesta seria 2 consultas individuales ... no 1 ... no puedes tirar en una sola columnas datos de columnas distintas ...

Comment: La consulta es correcta, lo que pides es algo que se tiene que solucionar en el front-end.

Comment: Si, es correcto se trataba del front, buen consejo